# Import OVA in Cloud Build filure due to dependency error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, ova

I tried to import OVA (from VMware Workstation) to GCP Compute Engine Instance, but whole process failed after VMDK disk image to RAW format conversion, when executing following activities in importer VM:

> `Apr 22 13:50:32 inst-translator-import-ovf-translate-translate-disk-l2myq startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: commandrvf: /bin/sh -c "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends google-cloud-sdk"`
>
> `Apr 22 13:50:40 inst-translator-import-ovf-translate-translate-disk-l2myq startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I can attach whole build log if, more information is needed.

Comment: At which step from [the import](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks) did you get stuck?

Comment: It was acctually, an [import of full OVA](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files).  Based on Cloud Build logs stored in Bucket, import of boot disk was successfull, but then it failed in `inst-translator-import-ovf-translate-translate-disk` VM while running `startup-script-url` with this:```INFO startup-script-url: guestfsd: error: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```

Answer (score 0):

Run the pre check tool to see if there is any compatibility issues pre/post [import](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/tree/master/cli_tools/import_precheck/)

Can you run the following command with the ‘--verbosity=debug’ when importing the image. Any import errors will present itself [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/import) :

gcloud compute instances import foob --source-uri gs://[BUCKET]/image.ova --os [OS-type] --zone [ZONE_NAME] --verbosity=debug

The initial error means that the given OS version isn't tested for compatibility, and note that you must configure the [bootloader correctly](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#configure_bootloader) so it is able to boot up on GCE. So remove any Spashimage, rhgb and kernel command line arguments.

Comment: I did run pre-check, it was fine, OS is also supported (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), currently I'm trying with VMDK disk import instead of full OVA, but it's still a failure only (it succeeded once however, without any particular reason). Full import log can be cheked here: https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/36043313

Comment: I was able to build it out in my environment by using a Cloud Image from Ubuntus's repo: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/  can you perhaps upload the daisy logs? just make sure to sanitize sensitive information from them. the path will look something like this: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/thomas-dev-ovf-import-bkt-us-west2  otherwise, I will able to successfully create an instance without any issues.